# "session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent" keep coming even after session_start() already on top

Tags: php, html, security, session, error-handling

I got "Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent". I cannot put the session_start() on top because i'm using "use Phppot\DataSource" and it will not work if i change their position.
The code that i made was like this :

```
<?php
use Phppot\DataSource;
session_start();
require_once 'web.php';
?>
```

Can someone help me solve this error ? Thanks!

Comment: The error message should contain the info where the output was actually started.

Comment: Headers already sent means that something was echoed out of php to the browser, preventing php to send cookies (to start a new session)

Answer (score 0):

move session_start() under <?php

sessions and other headers have to be set before anything is broadcasted, and it seems phppot is broadcasting something looking at the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check what is causing headers to be sent: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

So for debugging you could do something like

```php
<?php
use xxx;

if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    die("Headers unexpectedly sent from {$file}::{$line}");
}
session_start();
```

Note that `session_start()` as your first statement is generally not the proper solution to these kinds of issues...